# "we are not running any businesses, nor have we ever"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am applying for bursary for my college education. I wanted to write that my parents are public servants and they are supporting me studying abroad solely using their salaries and life savings. And I want to add this following sentence.

> "My family is not running any businesses, nor have we ever run any"

Is this sentence correct. If not, can you guys help me to make this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: how about "my parents are public servants and they are supporting me studying abroad solely using their salaries and life savings. We don't own any businesses."

Comment: @JamesK I want to express the idea that we have never run a business

Answer (score 1):

Here are some that I like:

**My family does not operate a business, nor have they ever.**

My family is back in India.  **They do not run a business, and they never have.**

**My family and I have never run a business.**

A lot of variations are valid, and your best option is to finish the whole paper and have someone proofread the final version.  It would take me awhile to talk about the issues here, because your English is very good already, and the issues are fine details.